# Karma with npm packages & scripts that use require

Tags: angularjs, npm, karma-runner, browserify

I'm testing with Karma. And I run into a problem. In one of my components that I test, I'm using `jquery-ui` from `npm`. `jquery-ui.js` has `require('jquery')` statement. When I configure karma to include my `jquery-ui.js` :

```
    files: [
      /* Core */
      'node_modules/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js',

      /* Components */
      'gom-datepicker.js',

      /* Tests */
      'test/*.Spec.js'
    ],
```

I get the error that:

> PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7) ERROR
>   ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
>   at c:/dev/gom/gom-datepicker/node_modules/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:1

How can I resolve this issue properly? What is the proper way to use npm packages in Karma Tests? Do I have to employ `browserify` somewhere in the middle?

Comment: Can you provide a broader picture of what you are doing? Is it client-side code you are testing? If so, why do you install it using npm? And then, of course, the browser does not know `require`. Is it server-side code? Why not test it through mocha in a more direct manner?